Error with new app in Expo with template tabs, what is causing the error?
New app created with Expo and tabs template, it created it successfully and when i go into it and run npx expo start it returns error:
/Users/maregreyling/Projects/AIMI/Development/AIMI-demo/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/utils/errors.js:123
throw error;
^
ReferenceError: ReadableStream is not defined
at Object. (/Users/maregreyling/Projects/AIMI/Development/AIMI-demo/node_modules/undici/lib/web/fetch/response.js:528:3)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object. (/Users/maregreyling/Projects/AIMI/Development/AIMI-demo/node_modules/undici/lib/web/fetch/index.js:11:5)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
What is the problem?

use nvm install 18 to install node v18.
then use nvm use 18 to switch your node version to v18.
this worked for me.
if you don't have nvm, use curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.5/install.sh | bash to install it.
Reload your shell configuration to enable nvm:
source ~/.bashrc For bash users
source ~/.zshrc  For zsh users

Thanks, upgrading to a latest node version fixed it for me
